# Get records from database only if children have at least one valid record

Tags: c#, sql

How do I get all the records from Categories that have at least one Variable EndDate null? (so if all Varibles are end dated, the Category should not be selected)

I have these 3 entities

```
public class CategoryType
{
        public int CategoryTypeId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
public class Category
{
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public int CategoryTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual CategoryType CategoryType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Variable> Variables { get; set; }
}
public class Variable
{
        public int VariableId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }        
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SearchFilter> SearchFilters { get; set; } 
}
```

I have a mapper that gets called from the service GetCategoryTypes

```
private async Task<List<FilterDataCategoryTypeDTO>> GetCategoryTypes()
{
     List<FilterDataCategoryTypeDTO> result = new();

     var categoryTypeListEntity = await _context.CategoryTypes
                    .OrderBy(o=> o.Name)
                    .ToListAsync();

     var catTypes = categoryTypeListEntity
                    .Select(s => ManualMapper.ConvertFilterDataCategoryTypeEntityToCategoryDTO(s))
                    .ToList();

     return catTypes;
}     

public static DTO.FilterDataCategoryTypeDTO? ConvertFilterDataCategoryTypeEntityToCategoryDTO(Entities.CategoryType entity)
{
      return entity == null ? null : new DTO.FilterDataCategoryTypeDTO
      {
           CategoryTypeId = entity.CategoryTypeId,
           Name = entity.Name,
           Categories = entity.Categories
                .OrderBy(o=> o.Name)
                .Where(c => c.EndDate == null && c.Variables.Where(r => r.CategoryId == c.CategoryId).Count() == 0)
                .Select(s => ConvertFilterDataCategoryEntityToCategoryDTO(s))
                .ToList()
      } 
}
```

For example CategoryId=24 should not be select because all EndDates are filled, should only return it if at least one row has EndDate NULL

```
VariableId  Name            CategoryId  EndDate
33          Tweet Id            24  2022-04-15
34          Id                  24  2022-04-15
35          Url                 24  2022-04-15
36          Type                24  2022-04-15
37          Width               24  2022-04-15
38          Height              24  2022-04-15
39          Media Key           24  2022-04-15
40          Preview Image Url   24  2022-04-15
```

Comment: "I have a mapper" is pretty vague, can you tell more about "a mapper"?

Comment: You want select all `Categories` if at least one Variable's EndDate is null in `Variables` list ?

Comment: Updated code. Yes select all Categories that have at least one Variable EndDate null, if they all are end dated then should not be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below snipped, you probabbly need to use `Any()` like:

```
Categories = entity.Categories
             .OrderBy(o => o.Name)
             .Where(c => c.EndDate == null && c.Variables.Any(r => r.CategoryId == c.CategoryId && r.EndDate == Null))
             .ToList()
```

This will return all Categories that theirs `EndDate` are null and at leat have one `Variable` with `Null` EndDate.

But below query will get all categories that their `Variable` list at least have one item with `EndDate = Null`

```
entity.Categories.OrderBy(o => o.Name)
                 .Where(c => c.Variables.Any(r => r.CategoryId == c.CategoryId && r.EndDate == Null))
                 .ToList()
```

If your Model relations established correctly then don't need the first partition of sub query like:

```
  entity.Categories.OrderBy(o => o.Name)
                     .Where(c => c.Variables.Any(r => r.EndDate == Null))
                     .ToList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following.  You need a groupby :

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Entity entity = new Entity();
            var results = entity.Variable
                .GroupBy(x => x.CategoryId)
                .Where(x => x.Any(y => y.EndDate.ToString().Length == 0))
                .SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => new { VariableId = y.VariableId, Name = y.Name, CategoryId = y.CategoryId, EndDate = y.EndDate }))
                .ToList();
                
 

        }
    }
    public class Entity
    {
        public List<CategoryType> CategoryTypeId { get; set; }
        public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
        public List<Variable> Variable { get; set; }

    }
    public class CategoryType
    {
        public int CategoryTypeId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public int CategoryTypeId { get; set; }
        public virtual CategoryType CategoryType { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Variable> Variables { get; set; }
}
    public class Variable
    {
        public int VariableId { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }        
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SearchFilter> SearchFilters { get; set; } 
    }
    public class SearchFilter
    {
    }
```